# Different @click event on component - VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom-events, bulma, buefy

My project start with VueJS and Buefy.

The component have two different actions click :

- **Click on Cyan area** -> redirection to other page **(Action 1)**
- **Click on Magenta area** -> show dropdown **(Action 2)**

[image]

But when I click to **Action 2**, always **Action 1** works.

Here my component :

```html
<MyComponent
  :projects="data"
  @click.native="actionOne()"
/>
```

And inside my component, I have dropdown (using Buefy component) :

```html
<p>{{ data.projects }}</p>
<BDropdown aria-role="list">
  <BButton
    slot="trigger"
    class="button"
    type="is-text"
    @click.prevent="actionTwo()"
  >
    <BIcon icon="dots-horizontal" />
  </BButton>
  <BDropdownItem aria-role="listitem">Update</BDropdownItem>
  <BDropdownItem aria-role="listitem">Archive</BDropdownItem>
</BDropdown>
```

I try to use different event modifier but I can't have the expected behavior :

- `stop`
- `prevent`

Comment: Did you try `@click.stop="actionTwo()"`?

Comment: Yes I try with `@click.stop` for **Action 2** but this event don't trigger the dropdown

Comment: Do you want to call your method when the dropdown menu is opened?

Comment: When I click on dropdown, `actionTwo()` should open the menu. However, only the first `@click`run. So I feel like I can't put a second event **inside** my component

Comment: Did you try @click.self="actionTwo()"?

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because of event bubbling. When you click on the dropdown element, the click event bubbles up to the cyan area. What you need to do is cancel the event bubbling for the dropdown element.

```
<BDropdown aria-role="list">
  <BButton
    slot="trigger"
    class="button"
    type="is-text"
    @click="actionTwo($event)"
  >
    <BIcon icon="dots-horizontal" />
  </BButton>
  <BDropdownItem aria-role="listitem">Update</BDropdownItem>
  <BDropdownItem aria-role="listitem">Archive</BDropdownItem>
</BDropdown>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        actionTwo(e) {
            e.cancelBubble = true
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I check event bubbling and I find a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `self` modifier.

```html
<MyComponent
  :projects="data"
  @click.native.self="actionOne()"
/>
```

As the documentation says:

> *only trigger handler if event.target is the element itself*
> *i.e. not from a child element*
> ([source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers))

Comment: I try to append `self` but only `actionTwo()` works

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem came to specific event from Dropdown component (Buefy). So I added `stop` modifier to Dropdown trigger click event and I added `prevent` in my component.

Here the solution :

```js
<MyComponent
  :projects="data"
  @click.native.prevent="actionOne()"
/>
```

```js
<BDropdown aria-role="list" @click.native.stop>
  <BButton
    slot="trigger"
    class="button"
    type="is-text"
  >
    <BIcon icon="dots-horizontal" />
  </BButton>
  <BDropdownItem aria-role="listitem">Update</BDropdownItem>
  <BDropdownItem aria-role="listitem">Archive</BDropdownItem>
</BDropdown>
```